# AngularJS clone select box on change and apply all select box values to the same model array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, clone

I need to clone select box on change and apply new value to newly cloned select box. Only original select box should be able to clone itself and it should always be in **none** selected option.
All values of cloned select boxes should be saved in an array.
Please find code below:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div id="space-for-additional-select"></div>
     <div new-select>
        <select ng-model="result[counter]" ng-selected="result[counter].id" ng-options="option as option.value for option in options">
            <option value="">Select</option>
        </select><br/><br/>
     </div>
   <button ng-click='showResult()'>Show result</button>
</div>
```

And the following AngularJS code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.result = [];

    $scope.counter = 0;

    $scope.options = [
        { id: 1, value: 'opt1' },
        { id: 2, value: 'opt2' },
        { id: 3, value: 'opt3' }
    ];
    $scope.showResult = function() {
    for (index = 0; index < $scope.result.length; ++index) {
          console.log($scope.result[index]);
        }
    }

}]);
app.directive("newSelect", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        compile: function(tElement, attrs) {
            return function($scope) {
                var content = tElement.children();
                    content.bind("change", function() {
                    $scope.counter = $scope.counter + 1;
                    angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-additional-select')).append(content.clone());
            });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Same option can be chosen multiple times.

The problem in this code is that new cloned select boxes are not pre-selected, and also original select is not in none selected mode after change.
Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6baek4o/)

Comment: doing a simple dom clone really isn't the right approach here. You need a new `ng-model` for each as well as whenever you manipulate the dom and angular directives are involved you need to use `$compile` or the directives won't work. Always think of the data model first and let angular manage the dom

Comment: as far as cloning options ... get to know the various utilities in angular api like `angular.copy()`. They are all listed right at the top of the main api menu

Comment: Thank you for comments @charlietfl, will check out  `angular.copy()`.

Answer (score 0):

As @charlietfl already mentioned, copying a DOM element is not really the right approach in the world of Angular.

If you need to create a multiple `<select>` elements, then you can use `ng-repeat` to create them. Also, base the selection of `<options>` on a model using `ng-model`. That way, you can simply clone the element in your controller to copy the `<select>` element.